# Call keycloak authenticated API with valid JWT token

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, postman, keycloak, access-token

I have created a simple spring boot application which I have authenticated using keycloak. When I call the service (http://localhost:8080/table1data), It redirects me to keycloak login [page](http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/) where I insert my realm username and password, then it returns me the data. Now everything is going fine till now.

I want another scenario. If my user already has the valid token of the respective realm and he wants to access the same [URL](http://localhost:8080/table1data) with correct token, then the user should not be redirected to the keycloak login [page](http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/) (which makes sense as user has the valid token). How can I create this scenario from within my spring boot application? i-e passing the token to the spring boot service which validates this token from keycloak instead of redirecting me to the login page. Any help or reference to online article please

**My Controller Code**

```
public class Table1Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ITable1Repository table1Repository;

    @GetMapping("/table1data")
    public List<Table1Entity> getAllTable1Data() {
        return table1Repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

PS : I had generated the token using postman (Image attached)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Authorization request in your HTTP request, with "Bearer *my-sample-token*" as a value, placing your token here.

---

**Example using postman**

In the Authorization tab you need to select the type *Bearer Token* and add your access token in the *Token* field.

[image: authorization configuration]

Which basically translates in a "Authorization: Bearer *your-token*" header in the HTTP request made by postman. Instead, I mostly use the *Inherit auth from parent* option, so if you work with request collections you can add your token to the collection itself and every request in the collection gets it.

You can also consider setting a larger access token lifespan if you are working with a keycloak test server, in order to avoid having to obtain one token so frequently.

Comment: Hi @Xtreme Biker thanks for the response, but I want to do it from within the application itself. Not from postman. I just shared the postman Image to show that I have fetched the valid token. Now how can I pass this token from my controller to Keycloak to access the service without redirection to realm login page.

Comment: Hello Mirza, that's okey, but you've got the response also for what you ask. Read the second paragraph, you need to add an authorization header to your HTTP request. For the header value, prepend "Header " to your access token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an

> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

:

```
@GetMapping(path="/table1data")
public ResponseEntity<List<Table1Entity>> getAllTable1Data(String bearer) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Table1Entity>>(service.findAll(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```